# unable make a pattern match

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've the below table in my HTML page.

```
  <div id="mDisplayCiteList_ctl00_mCiteListSpacingDiv">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="ResultListTableHeader">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="x">Content</span></td>
                <td><span class="x">Content1</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="x">Content</span></td>
                <td><span class="x">Content1</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and i'm trying to get the `td` elements into a list with the below condition.

The first `td` of `tr` shouldn't have `colspan` or class name as `ResultListTableHeader`.
I tried the below XPATH.

```
List<WebElement> multiBases = chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath(
                ".//*[@id='mDisplayCiteList_ctl00_mCiteListSpacingDiv']/descendant::table/descendant::tr[not(td[1]/@class='ResultListTableHeader' and td[1]/@colspan)]/td[4]/span"));
        for (int i = 0; i < multiBases.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(multiBases.get(i).getText());
        }
```

and this is not doing anything and also it isn't even throwing any exception.

Also i tried replacing `and` with `or`, but still no use.

**Expected output**

**here i want to get content1 (the third row second column) and content1 (the forth row second column), since the first column(td) of these rows doesn't have class name as ResultListTableHeader or colspan**

please let me know how can i fix this. Also if there is any alternate better way of doing this, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: For the provided example, what is your desired output?

Comment: Hi @alecxe, I've slightly modified my HTML to show the difference, here i want to get content1 (the third row second column) and content1 (the forthrow second column), since the first column(td) of these rows doesn't have class name as ResultListTableHeader or colspan

Comment: Please update HTML example so we can see how class 'ResultListTableHeader' will be used there.

Comment: Apologies for missing that out @DmytroPastovenskyi, Thanks for pointing that, I've updated the question.

Comment: Would you please add an result you expect to receive from that HTML?
Only td elements from last 2 tables, right?

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi, Yes, that's right, also updating my question

Comment: OK, got it. Answer is provided.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but the XPath you are looking for is as follows:

```
//table/tr/td[1][not(contains(@class, "ResultListTableHeader")) and not(@colspan)]/following-sibling::td[1]/span
```

This selects the `span` within the first `td` element that follows any `td` element which is the first child of a `tr` element, and doesn't have the class name `ResultListTableHeader` or the attribute `colspan`.

Comment: the question was about TD but not SPAN.

Comment: The question isn't exactly clear....! Both our answers are correct as far as I can see....

Comment: agree :) there are 2 things have been requested to do :)

Comment: My XPATH doesn't return anything, here when i used your XPATH and printed the size, it gives 0 as output

Answer (score 0):

So what say here is, returns all tr where first td match your conditions and than from these tr you get all td elements.

returns all DIV as you write in question.

```
/div[@id='mDisplayCiteList_ctl00_mCiteListSpacingDiv']/table/tr[not(td[1]/@class='ResultListTableHeader') and not(td[1]/@colspan)]/td
```

returns content1 and content1 as you also asked as well (content of second TD).

```
/div[@id='mDisplayCiteList_ctl00_mCiteListSpacingDiv']/table/tr[not(td[1]/@class='ResultListTableHeader') and not(td[1]/@colspan)]/td[2]/span
```

Comment: My XPATH doesn't return anything, here when i used your XPATH and printed the size, it gives 0 as output

Comment: @user3872094 it means you did not provide us with all details.
If you use online service: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output you will see that both: my and lambo xpath return what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you have shown, it looks like you want every other `TD` with class x. This should work for you and I think is more readable than a complex XPath.

```
List<WebElement> cells = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#mDisplayCiteList_ctl00_mCiteListSpacingDiv td.x"));
for (int i = 1; i < cells.size(); i = i + 2)
{
    System.out.println(cells.get(i).getText().trim());
}
```